# Error 83 error C2398: conversion from 'double' to 'float' requires a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, floating-point, compiler-bug

I have found many posts about this error but I could find how to overcome it.
This is the code where the error is triggered:

```
void main(){
    float f{1.3};
}
```

Why in the initialize-list no casting happened like any other variable? For example, this works smoothly:

```
float f = 1.3;
```

Comment: Sorry it should be something else I gonna post the full code

Comment: The `static_cast<float>(...)` needs to be wrapped around the entire second element. You are multiplying and dividing with doubles again, so you turn it back into a double implicitly.

Comment: @melak47 I tired but it is not the porblem cause they are integers not doubles

Comment: @JamesRoot you mean bitwise is processed first ???

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Nevermind I eat my words, I think that does work.

Comment: Downvoters please comment. I know it is long code but no way to reduce it while a chunk of it is working fine

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Seriously, why not just break up those statements into pieces that are easy to digest?  It isn't heroic because you can write code in two or less lines.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Each time I reduce the code the error gone! until I found where it is. Thanks anyway

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Actually, what you found isn't the problem. Try it: `float f{1.3};`. This will be accepted, because `1.3` is a constant. Only `double d{1.3}; float f{d};` gives a problem.

Comment: @hvd In my compiler, it is a problem. Your code did not compile. VS.NET 2013

Comment: @HumamHelfawi That seems like a compiler bug, but let me check the standard to make sure. Regarding your comment on my (now deleted) answer: if you're dealing with integers, then `std::max(rect1.height, rect2.height) / std::min(rect1.height, rect2.height)` won't do what you want. You need another cast to `float` there.

Comment: yes it will be consdried as **integer devided by integer** which will result in an **integer** result.

Comment: I am guessing the downvotes are because most people not reproduce. Which is why it is important to specify which compiler and using live examples can really help for Visual Studio you can use [webcompiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) and for gcc and clang [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) or  [wanbox](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/).

Comment: Unfortunately webcompiler does not allowing linking live example like other site but you can at least mention it is reproducible there and as long as you provide a full test case that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've commented that the use of `1.3` gives an error with your compiler. That means you've found a compiler bug. The standard is quite clear that this is not a narrowing conversion, so it should be allowed.

Quoting N4140 (roughly C++14):

> **8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]**
>
> 7 A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion
>
> [...]
>
> -- (7.2) from `long double` to `double` or `float`, or from `double` to `float`, **except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented**
>   (even if it cannot be represented exactly), or
>
> [...]

Your `1.3` is a constant expression well within the range of `float`.

I recommend reporting this to Microsoft, assuming it isn't a known issue already. Unfortunately, simply upgrading your Visual Studio won't fix this. I can reproduce the problem in VS2015.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Yeah, Visual Studio's compiler appears to check that the value can be represented exactly in `float`. `1.5` can be, since its binary representation (`1.1`) just requires a fixed number of two digits. `1.3` can't be, since it is a repeating decimal in binary, which gets cut off at the maximum precision of `double`, which is higher than the maximum precision of `float`, so would conceptually require rounding from `double` to `float`. But this is not how the standard says it should work.

Answer (score 5):

Forcing it to be float using the 'f' suffix avoids the narrowing conversion. the below works ..

```
float f{1.3f}
```

But i agree that the compiler should have taken care of it .. (as per the standard quoted by @hvd)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is C++, don't use c-style casts, try:

```
 static_cast<float>(std::abs(...))
```

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I [cannot reproduce the error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e5bf6fa2362e550), please provide a complete example if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry it should be something else I gonna post the full code

Comment: I also cant reproduce

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe a bug or something. Use this instead:

```
float f;
f=1.3;
```

Comment: To format code as a multi-line block, put four spaces in front of each line, and put a blank line before and after the code block.